# error :[object HTMLParagraphElement], when assignin a variable from a function

Tags: javascript, php

i have  a function that shows me if a file exists, if so he will return me the file path if it doesnt exist he will still give me the path so he can create the file:

```
function getnamechats($user1,$user2){
   
    $filename1="chats/chat".$user1."&".$user2.".json";
         $filename2="chats/chat".$user2."&".$user1.".json";
    if (file_exists($filename1)) {
        return $filename1;
    }
    else if (file_exists($filename2)) {
        return $filename2;
    }
    else{ return $filename1;}
}
```

it works fine on creating/opening the file to write on it,ive tested a lot of times and my json file gets updated everytime:

```
function send_chat($nick,$chat){
    global $userid;global $chatparse;
   $heasda=getnamechats($userid,$chatparse);
 $ok=$heasda;
    // read/write
    $filename = "$heasda";
    $fopen = fopen($filename,"r");
    $fgets = fgets($fopen);
    fclose($fopen);
    $decode = json_decode($fgets,true);
    // limit 10
    end($decode);
    if(key($decode) >= 10){
        array_shift($decode);
        $new_key =10;
    }
    else{
        $new_key = key($decode);
        $new_key++;}
    
    $format = array($nick,$chat);
    $decode[$new_key] = $format;
    $encode = json_encode($decode);
    // write
    $fopen_w = fopen($filename,"w");
    fwrite($fopen_w,$encode);
    fclose($fopen_w);
    
}
```

but in the function that opens/create it to read i get the following error the first variable is right(1) but the second one (suppost to be after the &) just doesnt work, and the error HTMLParagraphElement appears,example:

> chats/chat1&[object HTMLParagraphElement].json

i then called again the getnamechats() function as soon as a new msg is triggered just to check if the file still exists, if it does, it will send me the variable $heasda to show_chat($heasda) and basically it will do the same as send_chat, but instead writing on it, it will read it:

```
function show_chat($heasda){
   print_r($heasda);
    $filename = $heasda;
    $fopen = fopen($filename,"r");
    $fgets = fgets($fopen);
    fclose($fopen);
    $decode = json_decode($fgets,true);
    $val .= "<table  id='table' class=\"table table-condensed\">";
    foreach($decode as $post){
        
        $val .= "<tr><td><b style=\"color:#{$post[0]}\">{$post[0]}</b>: {$post[1]}</td></tr>";}
    
    $val .= "</table>";
    return $val;
}

if(isset($_POST["chat"]) && $_POST["chat"] != ""){
    $nick = $_SESSION['iduser'];
    $chat = $_POST["chat"];
    send_chat($nick,$chat); 
}

if(isset($_GET["chat"]) && $_GET["chat"] != ""){
    global $userid;global $chatparse;
   $heasda=getnamechats($userid,$chatparse);
    echo show_chat($heasda);
    exit;
}

?>
```

As someone said it can be JavaScript heres the code too, ive read about it but i still dont understand properly:

```
function autoloadpage() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "?chat=1&chat-pars="+secnum,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                $("div#chat").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The problem is in JavaScript, not PHP. You're trying to use a DOM element as if it's a string. You probably forgot to use `.innerText` to get the contents of the paragraph.

Comment: hello sir, thanks for replying, i added the javascript function can you tell me more detailed where im suppost to add .innetText? @Barmar

Comment: How do you set `secnum`? That's where it's coming from.

Comment: it is a hidden <p> getting header info "<p id="secnum" style="visibility:hidden"><?php echo $_GET['chat-pars'];?></p>" @Barmar

Comment: Basically you assign a wrong value to one of the GET parameters - `chat-pars` so if the only place you assign it is the above "autoloadpage" method - then show us where do you set the value of `secnum`. It's the element itself, not it's content most likely.

Comment: @vuryss i set it manually for now.. just creating a chat page, for testing so is manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`secnum` is a DOM element, not the text inside it. You need to get the text.

You should also call `encodeURIComponent` in case it contains characters that have special meaning in a URL.

```
function autoloadpage() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "?chat=1&chat-pars="+encodeURIComponent(secnum.innerText),
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            $("div#chat").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: well, the error disapeared, but now it doesnt return any number

Comment: Check that the hidden paragraph actually has the number that you expect.

Comment: it does sir , ive sett the visibility to visible and it shows  fine @barmar

Comment: thats strange, when i copied "encodeURIComponent(secnum.innerText)," and replaced by the old one it didnt work, now i just replaced all the function and it actually did work.. thank you!!@barmar